# How to handle HTML popup which appears as per database condition in selenium webdriver

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My Scenario is

1. Enter username, password and click on `Login` button.
2. system checking the condition in database as `this user already login = true`.
3. The pop up appears as `forcefully login` with `OK` and `Cancel` button.
4. Click on Pop up OK button.
5. Appearing Location drop down and GO button and system moving ahead.
6. If `this user already login = false`.
7. The pop up doesn't appear.
8. System executing step 5.

The question is 'how do i handle above Condition' ?
Because that pop up is not appearing each time

HTML code of pop up is:

```
    <div id="msgBox1473647409235" class="msgBox" style="background-image:  url("styles/images/msgBoxBackGround.png"); opacity: 1; top: 37px; left: 566.5px;">
    <div class="msgBoxTitle">Confirm</div>
    <div>
    <div class="msgBoxContainer">
    <div id="msgBox1473647409235Image" class="msgBoxImage">
    <img src="styles/images/confirm.png">
    </div>
    <div id="msgBox1473647409235Content" class="msgBoxContent">
    <p>
    <span>
    User already login
    <br>
    Forcefully Login?
    </span>
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="msgBox1473647409235Buttons" class="msgBoxButtons">
    <input id="msgBox1473647409235FirstButton" class="msgButton"  type="button" value="OK" name="OK">
    <input class="msgButton" type="button" value="Cancel" name="cancel">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming you're using Java) You just simply check using `findElements()` as below :-

```
//Enter login credentials and click on login button 

//Now check for popup if to be appears with Ok button 
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("msgBox"));
if(elements.size() > 0 && elements.get(0).isDisplayed() && elements.get(0).isEnabled())
{
    //Now find Ok or cancel button to process 
    WebElement okButton = element.get(0).findElement(By.name("OK"));

    WebElement cancelButton = element.get(0).findElement(By.name("cancel"));
}

//Not handle your 5 steps and more Appearing Location drop down and GO button and system moving ahead.
```

Comment: @ Saurabh.. Thank you...now its working, 
but there is another issue..when 'this user already login = false' ,system directly focusing on 'GO' button without selecting location from drop down..its working fine when pop up is appearing.

Comment: @Swa So you need do this step, selecting location from drop down outside the if condition because its common for both case..:)

Comment: Then it may be problem with dropdown selection, you can ask another question regarding this. Thanks..:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're meaning, but you can use a timestamp with in the database set one of the fields as a datetime, maybe with an ip address. Then each time the user navigate through the website it has a last access with in the database. you can do this through the same php scripts you're using to determine if the user has access to that page. Then to test if they are login you can simply check to see if the last access was with in a certain time length for example 30 minutes. If it's under 30 minutes, then you treat it as logged still logged in, etc.